# Attempt to update entity without persisting on it DOCTRINE

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Product entity with a ManyToOne relationship with Category.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;
}
```

```
class Category
{
    use BlameableTrait;

    ...
}
```

The Category entity implements a trait, with properties to record when a record is created, updated, etc.

```
use App\Entity\User\User;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

trait BlameableTrait
{
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @var User
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @var User|null
     *
     * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="update")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $updatedBy;

    public function getCreatedBy(): ?User
    {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy(?User $createdBy): self
    {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setUpdatedBy(?User $updatedBy): self
    {
        $this->updatedBy = $updatedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedBy(): ?User
    {
        return $this->updatedBy;
    }
}
```

When I try to update the product entity I have an error indicating that an error has occurred while trying to update the Category entity, but I have not indicated that it should be updated.

This only happens to me in the production environment and randomly, one time it works, another time it doesn't.
Locally, debugging the symfony profiler, for the same curl, only one update is done on the Product entity, which is fine.

I don't understand where Symfony or Doctrine try to update the Category entity.

Both the production and local environments run on the same Docker image.

Comment: Does your Symfony log have anything in production? (project root/var/log/prod.log)

Comment: Please update your question to include the controller method and/or form(s) that handle the submission, instantiation, and persisting of the entity. Please update your question to include the full source code for both entities as well. The update error typically happens due to improper add/remove method declarations for the relationship that does not account for the existing association(s), which then tries to add duplicate entities to the database and fails.